Optimizing a function using Python
I have the following optimization problem where ( a ) refers to an index in an array of length ( K = 4 ):
$$
 \sup_{w \in W} \inf_{\lambda \in L} \sum_{a=1}^{K} w_a. \frac{(\mu_{a} - \lambda_{a})^2}{2} 
$$
where:

W  is a vector of vector which has a total of 268 vectors and each vector is of length 4.
L  is also a vector of vectors which has a total of 2017200 vectors and each vector is of length 4. .
$ \bf\mu $ is a vector of length 4.

So I want to write my function as $\bf\ f (\mu , W , L)$ and I want to find a function $\bf\ g(\mu , W) $ after minimizing with respect to $\bf\ L$.
Similarly I want to maximize the function $\bf\ g(\mu , W) $ to get a function $\bf\ h(\mu)$. I want to use python to perform the above optimization.
I am not understanding how the function works, how to model the problem and how to get some function as output from optimization and whether that is necessary to solve the problem.
Also the big size of $\bf\ L$ poses a big problem in terms of efficiency.

Roughly 2 million vectors of size 4 vectors seems like a small enough problem to be handled with NumPy vectorization, although if speed is really important then you may want to run this in parallel. Here's an example of NumPy code (not in parallel) that should run this- assuming I understood your question:
import numpy as np

f = lambda mu, w, lambd: np.sum(w * (mu - lambd)**2) / 2
g = lambda mu, w, L: np.min([f(mu, w, lambd) for lambd in L])
h = lambda mu, W, L: np.max([g(mu, w, L) for w in W])

print(f"Optimized Value: {h(mu, W, L)}")


There are $268 \times 2017200 \approx 2^{20.1}$ different pairs of $w,\lambda$.  For each, evaluate the inner sum.  Then, it's easy to find the optimal value.  Each inner sum can be evaluated in a handful of operations (say, under 16 of them), so the total number of operations will be something like $2^{24.1}$.  This is small enough that the computation will be easy for a computer to perform, probably in under a second.
